# Unable to import opencv in anaconda windows

Tags: python, windows, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I am not able to import OpenCV in anaconda. I am able to install OpenCV package in anaconda command prompt, but I don't know how to import it into spyder

Comment: Do you have some errors in prompt?

Comment: Please see [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to solve this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import cv2
```

instead of:

```
import opencv
```